# How to load quickly the image from the url in the ImageView of the normal android view(not list view)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

My internet connection is very fast. Despite that my image loads very slow in the app. Here is the code i have been using. As suggested I have been using async method to perform certain task seperately..

```
public class ItemPage extends Activity{
ImageView image;
String url;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
//getting url from the parent activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null) url = extras.getString("bigurl");
//async call
           new DownloadFilesTask().execute(); 
}

 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { //working part
                     Drawable drawable;

                     @Override
                     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                     try {
                        drawable =drawableFromUrl(url);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                      return null;
                     }
                     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                         image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    }          
                } 
              public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
                    Bitmap x;

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

                    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    return new BitmapDrawable(x);
                }
}
```

Please help me. Is there any way to load the image faster from the url? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Use network monitor (ddms) to check the speed at which you are downloading. Caching could help but there is very little you can do on your app for faster download of images. Try using a faster server for image delievery

Comment: Serer loads fine. But for image its taking 30ms.

Comment: how big is the image that you are loading and what is the format and how big is the imageview (in dips)

source width & height in pixels, bitmap format (png, jpg, ?), bit depth (8,16,24,32 bits per pixel)

Comment: honestly  30ms is very fast how fast you want it to be?

Comment: @dangVarmit: picture is of 500*500 jpg format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to use Aquery Library .
it is load images very speedly.

refer this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

Comment: Thanks its loads very speed

Answer (score 0):

```
My internet connection is very fast. Despite that my image loads very slow in the app.
```

It doesnt mean you can download image very fast when you have a really fast connection, it could be that the web server have a limit download speed for each connection, or the server is far from your current location. I would recommend to check the download speed of the server you are trying to connection first, if it is slow then it is not code but the server itself.

Comment: I think its not on the server part. Is there any way in the code part to make it faster?

Comment: @user3890749 that is the best way to get image from server there no other code that can be better than that. and yes it is the server or the phone itself

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
    Bitmap mIcon_val;
URL newurl;
private void loadImage() {

    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do second step
            try {
                newurl = new URL(image_url);
                mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 123;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    };
}
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 123:
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
            break;

        }
    }
};
```

For calling the thread, you can use

```
backgroundThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try using picasso library.it has several functions to compress,crop images that may help in downloading images at better rates.the link provides the full documentation of usage of the library-
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can do to speed up the image processing side of things.

When you decode the stream you are converting it to an in-memory raster format.  A 32bit image at 500x500 will take 1 mb of memory (500x500x4bytes).   the native pixel format varies by device, and the fastest performance is to match the bitmap's pixel format to the system's pixel format so the system doesn't need to convert the image from it's native format to the window format.

Older devices in particular will use the 16 bit format.  The image would be stored at 32bits, and then converted to 16bits when it's drawn to the screen.  On these devices, you would be saving half the memory storage and avoiding a costly pixelwise conversion by decoding the image at 16 bits instead of at 32 bits.  On newer devices that have the memory, it's better to store the image at 32 bits to avoid the conversion penalty.

So somewhere early on,  store the pixel format that is used by the system.  It will either be a 16 bit format (RGB_565) or a 32 bit format (8bits per pixel per color)

```
    // default to 32 bits per pixel
    Config bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 ; //RGB_565 | ARGB_8888

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int bmp_cfg = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getPixelFormat();
    if (bmp_cfg == PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 || bmp_cfg == PixelFormat.RGBX_8888 || bmp_cfg == PixelFormat.RGB_888){
        bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    } else {
        bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    }
```

Later, when you are decoding the bitmap, use the window manager's default pixel format so that it will create the bitmap with the correct pixel format while decoding (rather than converting in a second pass)

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = bitmapConfig;  // match pixel format to widnow system's format
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);               
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
```

You can also play with the sample size to adjust the bitmap, but at 500x500 you probably need the whole image anyway.